# DeviceMonitor constantly gives the error "failed to start monitoring emulator-5554", how should I fix it?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I ran eclipse once with desired output on the emulator, but when I ran another project, after some times giving the last output, I've been constantly getting DeviceMonitor error: "Failed to start monitoring emulator-5554", do you have any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: Have you tried restarting ADB?

Comment: @Brandon No, I haven't actually. I'm not working on this project anymore and I don't work with the emulator but the mobile phone itself. Thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you have only one emulator running, try

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

This should restart the adb server connection.

Comment: ,As I said to Brandon, I'm not working with the emulator anymore.But I'll take your advice in the same situation.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I have sometime same problem with emulator i generally prefer to clean the all the project or right click on emulator from DDMS and click on restart ADB or final ways is to restart the eclipse as it is not feasible solution but it work for me

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Android Studio. I clicked on the device drop down menu and clicked "AVD Manager". Then I right clicked the emulator and deleted it. Then I clicked on "Create Virtual Device" button in the same window and created the same emulator again. Then when I clicked on "Run app" button, it worked without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

I agree. In fact I find that deleting the emulator then reinstating it solves a lot of problems.
I have had the 'run app' command fail for all sorts of reasons but this sorts them out.
BTW I'm running under Windows- I understand Unix is a lot less flakey.

Answer (score 0):

Try newer version on AVD and update your SDK

Answer (score 0):

I found that having the USB debugging activated on my phone was causing the AVD Manager in android studios throw the adb connection error. hope this helps some other people.

I attempted all the common fixes and the problem persisted. However I realized that my phone was always the prioritized device when I restart android studios. I ran my app on my phone and there was now connection error. So I figured it was a long shot but maybe the adb server was prioritizing my device over the virtual device. Sure enough switching off USB debugging options on my phone removed it from the list of devices and now my virtual devices are all working Perfect!!

Answer (score 0):

Click on the device or so called emulator, and just clear the data or wipe the data.
It handsomely worked for me.