# Cannot start Android Studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, android-emulator, emulation

Im trying to start my emulator on Android Studio but everytime I try it always crash and show this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEM29.png)

Here is my laptop spec :
[My laptop spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goMpg.png)

What should I do ?

Comment: Please do not post error messages inside a screen shot. Copy the messages and paste them into your question.

Comment: try one of these answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355942/devicemonitor-constantly-gives-the-error-failed-to-start-monitoring-emulator-55

Answer (score 0):

have you tried deleting the emulator then reinstating it?

This can solve a lot of problems.

OR :

run these commands from the Terminal:

> adb kill-server
>
> adb start-server